# ExecuteSqlCommand in .NET Core

Tags: entity-framework, .net-core

Is ASP.NET Core the only platform implementing 
[Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.RelationalDatabaseFacadeExtensions.ExecuteSqlCommand](https://apisof.net/catalog/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.RelationalDatabaseFacadeExtensions.ExecuteSqlCommand(DatabaseFacade,String,Object())) in .NET Core 1.0.1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That class is part of `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational` nuget package.

If you look at it in NuGet you can find it [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational/).

It is supported on .NET Core 1.0 and above, and .NET Framework 4.5.1 and above.

Comment: Thanks for finding that NuGet package!  [link]https://apisof.net/catalog/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.RelationalDatabaseFacadeExtensions.ExecuteSqlCommand(DatabaseFacade,String,Object()) should be updated.

Comment: As it turned out, all I needed was to add 'using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore' for this extension method. I didn't need to add the 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational' package. Perhaps it is included with the 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore' or 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer' metapackages which are included in this project.

Comment: Well, not sure, but [this search](http://packagesearch.azurewebsites.net/?q=RelationalDatabaseFacadeExtensions%20ExecuteSqlCommand) indicates it is on the `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational` package. Maybe you have added it indirectly? and yes the `using` is mandatory for extension methods

Comment: Yea, as it turned out, I simply missed a reference. I was distracted by the fact that https://apisof.net/catalog/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.RelationalDatabaseFacadeExtensions.ExecuteSqlCommand(DatabaseFacade,String,Object()) does not include .NET Core on the list of platforms. Thanks for the link to http://packagesearch.azurewebsites.net/?q=RelationalDatabaseFacadeExtensions%20ExecuteSqlCommand. That resource includes the package name. From what I have gathered, it seems that Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational maybe included in the Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore metapackage.